# DevExpress Controls for Responsive Web Design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, devexpress, controls

I am Web Designer and I want to know how to use DevExpress Controls in Responsive Bootstrap Template.

Comment: Have you tried something? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: yes I have used some controls like grid view ribbon control which requires width and after that width responsiveness is just lost completely.

Comment: Try adding a sample code! And then tell how it behaves; and how you want it to behave instead! And then wait, for awesome replies ;)

Comment: I am using bootstrap classes like grid classes and inserting controls in that but these are looks as fixed size controls all the time, sorry I am not able to post anything please help me out.

Comment: I am not an expert in what you are asking for! I am just trying to help your question get more attention! Do as I say if you want satisfactory replies.

Comment: Thank you so Much friend. I will try whatever I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [How to make DevExpress web controls responsive](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=T250229) guide to learn more about DevExpress ASP.NET responsive/adaptive features available out of the box and how to proceed when building the entire responsive/adaptive page layout.